# How to detect the click of blank space in Pull To Refresh Grid View?

Tags: android

In my application I have set a grid view over a fragment.I have used **Chrisbanes library** for Pull To Refresh Grid View. Height and width of pull to Refresh Grid View is fill parent because if I give height as wrap content then it does not work.

My Grid View can have maximum 3 rows and 3 columns (total 9 images) at a time. Now the problem is if less than 9 images appear at a time  on grid view, and I want to perform some action on click of blank space, then I am unable to detect the click of blank space. I tried **OnClickListener** on pull to refresh but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no images loaded, you won't be able to launch a `OnClickListenerEvent` at a blank position.

Have you thought about using a transparent image?

If less than 9 images are loaded into your `GridView`, fulfill the remaining with a transparent image.

[image]

Then add a `ClickEvent` when `v.getId() == R.drawable.transparentimage`

That should do the work.